# MySQL: хранение отмеченных сheckbox-флажков

Tags: php, mysql, массивы, post

Есть таблица

```
idv dekad_podvid
1   красный
5   зеленый
3   синий
```

Делаю запрос

```
$sql = "SELECT * FROM dekad_podvid ORDER BY idv ASC";
$query = mysql_query($sql) or die("Ошибка: " . mysql_error());

while($row = mysql_fetch_array($query)) { 

    $idv=$row[0];
    $podvid=$row[1];

echo "<input type='checkbox' name='podvid[]' id='podvid' value='$idv' >";
echo $podvid;
```

Выводит корректно, однако не знаю как обработать этот массив далее.

Нужно: принять через POST выставленные галочки и выполнить запрос вида

```
SELECT * FROM table WHERE "полученные галочки"
```

Answer (score 2):

Для того, чтобы решить задачу сохранения флажков, не достаточно одной таблицы `dekad_podvid`. Ее нужно либо расширить столбцом `values` для хранения отмеченных флажков, либо создать дополнительную таблицу `dekad_podvid_values` со следующей структурой

```
CREATE TABLE dekad_podvid_values (
  id int(11) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  idv int(11) NOT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (id)
);
```

Отдельная таблица может быть удобна, в том случае, если потребуется хранить разные состояния флажков для разных пользователей (когда могут потребоваться несколько наборов и дополнительные поля для обозначения принадлежности отдельным пользователям).

HTML-форма для флажков может выглядеть следующим образом

```
<?php
require_once('handler.php');
?>
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="ru">
<head>
  <title>Редактирование состояния флагов</title>
  <meta charset='utf-8'>
</head>
<body>
  <form method='POST'>
    <?php
      foreach($podivs as $podiv) {
        $checked = in_array($podiv['idv'], $values) ? 'checked' : '';
        echo "<input type='checkbox' name='podvid[]' id='podvid' ".
             "value='{$podiv['idv']}' $checked>{$podiv['dekad_podvid']}<br />";
      }
    ?>
    <input type='submit' value='Добавить'><br />
  </form>
</body>
</html>
```

Обработчик handler.php выполняет две функции, создает массивы `$podivs` для формирования флажков и `$values` с сохраненными флажками. Кроме того, он обрабатывает POST-данные, поступающие из формы.

В вопросе вы используете устаревшее расширение mysql. В настоящий момент оно признано устаревшим, более того, исключено из PHP 7. Поэтому далее ответ ориентируется на расширение PDO. Файл handler.php может выглядеть следующим образом

```
<?php
require_once('connect.php');
try {
  // Обработчик формы
  if(!empty($_POST)) {
    // Удаляем старые данные
    $query = 'DELETE FROM dekad_podvid_values';
    $pdo->exec($query);
    // Вставляем новые данные
    if(count($_POST['podvid'])) {
      $values = [];
      foreach($_POST['podvid'] as $value) {
         $values[] = "(NULL, ".intval($value).")";
      }
      $query = 'INSERT INTO dekad_podvid_values
                VALUES '.implode(',', $values);
      $pdo->exec($query);
    }

    header("Location: {$_SERVER['PHP_SELF']}");
    exit();
  }

  // Данные для флажков формы
  $query = 'SELECT * FROM dekad_podvid ORDER BY idv ASC';
  $pdv = $pdo->query($query);
  $podivs = $pdv->fetchAll();    
  // Идентификаторы отмеченных флажков
  $query = 'SELECT idv FROM dekad_podvid_values';   
  $val = $pdo->query($query);
  $values = $val->fetchAll(PDO::FETCH_NUM | PDO::FETCH_COLUMN);
}
catch (PDOException $e) {
  echo "Ошибка выполнения запроса: {$e->getMessage()}";
}
```

Для установки соединения с базой данных используется файл connect.php, который может быть оформлен следующим образом

```
<?php
  try {
    $pdo = new PDO(
      'mysql:host=localhost;dbname=test',
      'root',
      '',
      [PDO::ATTR_ERRMODE => PDO::ERRMODE_EXCEPTION, PDO::ATTR_EMULATE_PREPARES => true]);
  }
  catch (PDOException $e) {
    echo "Невозможно установить соединение с базой данных";
  }
?>
```